# What is the use of multiple classes

Tags: c#

I'm studying C# as a student and I stumbled upon this.

```
class Student
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last {get; set;}
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public List<int> Scores;
}
```

Why would someone make a separate class for a few variables?

Comment: Maybe to group them into a meaningful object??

Comment: It is the core principle of OOP

Comment: Why the downvotes?  Get out of your ivory towers, it's a reasonable question and one asked by someone paying attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Reason 1

### To make the code easier to understand.

(*Don't underestimate how important easy to understand code is*)

Imagine this:

```
class Student
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last {get; set;}
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int[] Scores { get; set; }
}

class SomethingComplex
{
    public void AComplexThing_1(string first, string last, int id, string street, string city, int[] scores)
    {
        // do something
    }

    public void AComplexThing_2(Student student)
    {
    }
}
```

When calling the `AComplexThing_1` the method will look like `AComplexThing_1("Al","Williams", 12345, "Highbridge", "Liverpool", new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9});` which is hard on the eyes, for a more complex and less intuative set od data this method would quickly become a nightmare to work with.  However, creating a student object keeps things readable, even if there were hundreds of properties.

## Reason 2

### We can serialize objects

We might want to return this over HTTP (as an example).  Having lots of individual variable is hard to handle, however, if they are all in an object (`DTO`) then we can use Serializers to convert the object to text like XML or JSON (or binary or whatever) and then back into an object again.

## Reason 3

### It's OOP

You are working in an Object Orientated Language, the entire framework and tooling expects you to work with objects.  If you do it, your life will become much, much easier.

## Reason ...

There are lots of other reasons people could add, those are the main ones I can thing of off the bat.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all since you are learning C# i think it is a good idea to read a Book about C#.
   For example : 
   Head First C# - http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920027812.do

   C# 5.0 in a Nutshell - http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023951.do?green=79F4A289-A404-5C1D-B0D4-B96CD2771BC9&intcmp=af-mybuy-0636920023951.IP

   or another book. There is a Chapter about Classes in almost every C# book. Read it and it will be much clearer to you.
2. In your example we create the Student class because those Properties represent an Object
   Student. We wrap information about Student in one Class so we can easily Create and reuse
   this structure.

   `class Student
   {
       public string First { get; set; }
       public string Last { get; set; }
       public int ID { get; set; }
       public string Street { get; set; }
       public string City { get; set; }
       public List<int> Scores;
   }`

If you add to that code a Constructor like this and test it in a TestClass to se what is the difference :

`class Student    {
        public string First { get; set; }
        public string Last { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public List<int> Scores;`

```
    public Student(string First, string Last, int ID, string Street, string City, List<int> Scores)
    {
        this.First = First;
        this.Last = Last;
        this.ID = ID;
        this.Street = Street;
        this.City = City;
        this.Scores = Scores;
    }
}

class TestStudentClass
{
    public void Test()
    {
        Student student1 = new Student("Student1", "Student1LastName", 1, "Street Name", "Some City", new List<int>());
        Student student2 = new Student("Student2", "Student2LastName", 2, "Street Name", "Some City", new List<int>());
        Student student3 = new Student("Student3", "Student3LastName", 3, "Street Name", "Some City", new List<int>());
        Student student4 = new Student("Student4", "Student4LastName", 4, "Street Name", "Some City", new List<int>());

        // not like this

        //For student1
        string Student1First = "Student1";
        string Student1Last = "Student1LastName";
        int Student1ID = 1;
        string Student1Street = "Street Name";
        string Student1City = "Some City";
        List<int> Student1Scores = new List<int>();

        //For student2
        string Student2First = "Student2";
        string Student2Last = "Student2LastName";
        int Student2ID = 2;
        string Student2Street = "Street Name";
        string Student2City = "Some City";
        List<int> Student2Scores = new List<int>();

        // and so on
    }
}`
```

You can see where it is going. The code to Create every Student would be too long and if you want to pass that Student to a method you would have to pass 6 variables.

```
        Student student1 = new Student("Student1", "Student1LastName", 1, "Street Name", "Some City", new List<int>());
        SomeMethod(student1);

        //or 

        SomeMethod("Student1", "Student1LastName", 1, "Street Name", "Some City", new List<int>());
```

With a Student Class you can give Student aditional behavior, use it like a Type in other classes and so on.

3. Read in the book that I mentioned about encapsulation and other OOP principles. 
   Also Read about SOLID. There are many good Articles on SOLID.